# Skip the Wait element message "The flow interview is now waiting" in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, wait-element

I used the wait element in my flow, it follows the screen where user adds some inputs including date/time and thats basically until when the flow is paused.
My problem is that when I reach the wait element it will bring screen to the user with following message:

> The flow interview is now waiting. It will resume in the background later.

Id like to avoid this screen or at least be able to customize to say some meaningfull info to the user. Is that possible?